# Fire Facebook pixel event on Woocommerce button click

Tags: woocommerce, facebook-pixel

I would like to fire a FB pixel AddToCart Event after a user clicked a Woocommerce button. I could use a plugin that works perfectly fine. But I would rather not use a plugin for such a "simple" task. The standard tracking code is implemented and working.

I then used the recommended FB code snippet from the helper tool, but it does not fire:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('ToCartButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  fbq('track', 'AddToCart', {
    value: 12,
    currency: 'EUR',
    content_type: 'Produkt',
  });
}, false);

<button id="ToCartButton"...
```

Using onclick, on the other hand, works:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  fbq('track', 'AddToCart', {
    value: 12,
    currency: 'EUR',
    content_type: 'Produkt',
  });
}
</script>

<button onclick="myFunction()"...
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Did you put your script after your button?

Comment: No, the script comes first. Should I put it after the button?

Comment: Yes, at the end, before the closing `body` tag.